# get a c# object from json

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I have this call

```
request.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

and get back a json object like

```
{“Email”:"my@Email.de",”Name”:”Stefan”}
```

How I get the value form the string back in an object? The user object is user.email and user.name .

Regards
Stefan

Comment: What you're trying to do is called "deserialization". At which point do you want to deserialize this JSON string again, and why?

Comment: I want to bring each part of the JSON string into the right textbox on a website. This JSON string is a result from an Azure AD call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways to achieve this:

1. you can use [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) to work with json:

   ```
   JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
   string Name = (string)jObject["Name"];
   string Email = (string)jObject["Email"];
   ```
2. you can use JavascriptSerilizer

   ```
   JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   User user = (User)json_serializer.DeserializeObject(json);
   ```
3. or you can use DataContractJsonSerilizer like this:

   ```
   public static T Deserialize<T>(string json)
   {
     T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json));
     DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
     obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
     ms.Close();
     return obj;
   }
   ```